# Function calls in React to deployed contracts return nothing

Tags: solidity, web3js, react

I have a simple lottery contract. When I call functions to it from Remix IDE I get the expected result. However, when I make calls to it from React, I get nothing back (such as from manager() or getPlayers()). I am, however, able to get the contract balance. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but my code is below:

**Lottery.sol:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.8.0;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;

    constructor() {
        // The manager will be the person deploying the contract
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier restrictedToManager() {
        require(
            msg.sender == manager,
            "This function is restricted to the manager"
        );
        _;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        // Players must stake at least 0.01 ether to be entered into the lottery
        require(
            msg.value >= 0.01 ether,
            "Players must stake at least 0.01 ether to be entered into the lottery"
        );

        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function random() private view returns (uint256) {
        // Pseudo-random number generator
        return
            uint256(
                keccak256(
                    abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players)
                )
            );
    }

    function pickWinner() public payable restrictedToManager {
        // Get a random player
        uint256 index = random() % players.length;

        // Pay the random player the balance on this contract
        payable(players[index]).transfer(address(this).balance);

        // Clear the array of players
        players = new address[](0);
    }

    function getPlayers() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return players;
    }
}
```

**web.js**

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

export default web3;
```

**lottery.js**

```
import web3 from './web3';

const address = '0x89a7a5d894797a6f26ACA2E5f2F3b39f29bB9f96';

const abi = [
    {
        inputs: [],
        stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
        type: 'constructor',
        constant: undefined,
        payable: undefined,
        signature: 'constructor'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'enter',
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: 'payable',
        type: 'function',
        constant: undefined,
        payable: true,
        signature: '0xe97dcb62'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'getPlayers',
        outputs: [[Object]],
        stateMutability: 'view',
        type: 'function',
        constant: true,
        payable: undefined,
        signature: '0x8b5b9ccc'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'manager',
        outputs: [[Object]],
        stateMutability: 'view',
        type: 'function',
        constant: true,
        payable: undefined,
        signature: '0x481c6a75'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'pickWinner',
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: 'payable',
        type: 'function',
        constant: undefined,
        payable: true,
        signature: '0x5d495aea'
    },
    {
        inputs: [[Object]],
        name: 'players',
        outputs: [[Object]],
        stateMutability: 'view',
        type: 'function',
        constant: true,
        payable: undefined,
        signature: '0xf71d96cb'
    }
];

export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import web3 from './web3';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import lottery from './lottery';

function App() {
  const [manager, setManager] = useState('');
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState('');
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [winMessage, setWinMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadWeb3() {
      const manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();

      setManager(manager);
      update();
    }

    loadWeb3();
  }, []);

  async function update() {
    const players = await lottery.methods.getPlayers().call();
    const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(lottery.options.address);

    setPlayers(players);
    setBalance(balance);
  }

  async function onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    setLoading(true);
    await lottery.methods.enter().send({ from: accounts[0], value: web3.utils.toWei(value, 'ether') });
    update();
    setLoading(false);
  }

  async function onClick() {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    setLoading(true);
    await lottery.methods.pickWinner().send({ from: accounts[0] });
    update();
    setWinMessage('A winner has been picked!');
    setLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Lottery Contract</h2>
      <p>This contract is managed by {manager}.
        There are currently {players.length} people entered,
        competing to win {web3.utils.fromWei(balance, 'ether')} ether!
      </p>
      <hr />
      {loading ? <p>Waiting for transaction to complete...</p> :
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <h4>Want to try your luck?</h4>
            <div>
              <label>Amount of ether to enter</label>
              <input
                value={value}
                onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)}>
              </input>
              <button type="submit">Enter</button>
            </div>
          </form>

          <hr />

          <h4>Ready to pick a winner?</h4>
          {winMessage && <h5>{winMessage}</h5>}
          <button onClick={onClick}>Pick a winner!</button>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you connect to metamask? https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#basic-considerations

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure I am since whenever I make a transaction using my app the meta mask extension pops up for permission to send funds

Comment: Does any error appear on the browser console?

Comment: No errors in the browser console

Comment: Since web3 is initialized on import perhaps it is a little too early. I'd try to initialize dynamically when loadWeb3 is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that it was an issue with my abi. As you can see in my abi, outputs was listed as outputs: [[Object]]. This is because I was getting my abi from a console log output and it wasn't spitting out the entire object. To get the entire object, I had to use util.inspect. Anyways, here is my corrected lottery.js file:

**Lottery.js:**

```
import web3 from './web3';

const address = '0x89a7a5d894797a6f26ACA2E5f2F3b39f29bB9f96';

const abi = [
    {
        inputs: [], stateMutability: 'nonpayable', type: 'constructor'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'enter',
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: 'payable',
        type: 'function'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'getPlayers',
        outputs: [{ internalType: 'address[]', name: '', type: 'address[]' }],
        stateMutability: 'view',
        type: 'function'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'manager',
        outputs: [{ internalType: 'address', name: '', type: 'address' }],
        stateMutability: 'view',
        type: 'function'
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: 'pickWinner',
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: 'payable',
        type: 'function'
    },
    {
        inputs: [{
            internalType: 'uint256', name: '', type: 'uint256'
        }],
        name: 'players',
        outputs: [{ internalType: 'address', name: '', type: 'address' }],
        stateMutability: 'view',
        type: 'function'
    }
];

export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

Comment: facing the same problem can you elaborate how you use util.inspect

Comment: the whole ABI is an array so, how would we will use .inspect method inside array

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ,

```
console.log(abi)
```

use

```
var util = require('util');    
console.log(util.inspect(abi,false,null,true));
```

to get correct abi